# Why use "ensure" during Ruby exception handling?

Tags: ruby, exception

Using begin => rescue => else => ensure => end blocks, doesn't the code after the "end" run no matter what?  Couldn't I just put what I would put in "ensure" after "end"?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure runs no matter what, even if exceptions are raised in your rescue block.

Comment: So, if an exception is raised in the rescue block, the ensure block will run, and then the script will crash?

Comment: No, exceptions raised in the rescue must be handled. Separately. The idea is that the ensure block will be run even if the code in the `begin...rescue` terminates prematurely. You often use this to release a resource.